# Global Header for PHP with S3 Client

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, header, phar

I have a global header file in a directory that I use to check the user has the correct credentials, and require / include important classes. Every PHP page includes this header file;

```
    //Connect to Amazon AWS - Include Amazon AWS SDK - Using PHAR Method
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'php/aws.phar');

    // Instantiate the S3 client with hardcoded AWS credentials
    $s3Client = new Aws\S3\S3Client([
        'version'     => 'latest',
        'region'      => 'us-east-1',
        'credentials' => [
            'key'    => 'MY-KEY',
            'secret' => 'MY-SECRET',
        ],
    ]);
```

Where the MY-KEY and MY-SECRET are correct.

I am then trying to use the created S3 Client class above throughout my web pages, but it doesn't work. It only seems to work if I copy the above code out of the header file and put it locally within the relevant PHP document.

The document I am currently working with does HTTP POST a form to carry out the action;

```
//Include connection details and check valid credentials
include_once '../php/header.php';

...

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    //Use Amazon S3 Client to upload the file

    .... //IF THE HEADER CODE IS INSERTED HERE THE CODE WORKS   

    $result = $s3Client->putObject(array(
        'Bucket' => 'MY-BUCKET',
        'Key'    => $filepath,
        'SourceFile' => $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]
    ));
}
```

Can anybody explain why my header setup isn't working. I don't want to duplicate the S3 Client credentials. Thanks.

Comment: You need to define "doesn't work." What's the error?

Comment: The putObject function doesn't trigger at all. But if I copy the top code out of the header and into the file locally, it suddenly works.

Comment: Then your file isn't getting included. See the answer below, maybe you need to use `require` instead to ensure it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `require_once('../php/header.php');` Then the code will not execute until that is included. Also, if include_once is returning false after execution it means it is not being included and there may be an issue with the include script.